# After canceling a Facebook App submission, do you have to wait a while before resubmitting

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I submitted my Facebook app for review then noticed I made an error so I cancelled the submission.

I then fixed my error and when I try to "Select items to include in the submission", and click "Add Items" button, nothing happens...

I have tried logging out and in, different browsers, different users but all have the same issue: when I click the "Add Items" button, nothing happens...

Comment: No, you don’t have to wait. But there is a current bug with this, they are working on a fix. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/509086772591739

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much, your a champ!